# Django models dependencies

Tags: django, database, django-models, model

I am new at Django Python. Need help

I am writing Calory Counter. I have models Food (list of foods with calories, etc), Profile (store all selected foods through model Postfood) and Recipes. The question is how I can add recipe to my ration (Profile) .

```
My models:



class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    measure = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, default=0)
    calorie = models.FloatField(null=False, default=0)
    carbohydrate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, null=True)
    fats = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, null=True)
    protein = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, null=True)
    person_of = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey('Receipe', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Receipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
    portion = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, null=False)
    calorie = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank = True)
    carbohydrate =models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, null=True)
    fats = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, null=True)
    protein = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, null=True)
    time = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=20, blank=True)
    difficulty_level_options = (
                                ('easy', 'easy'),
                                ('medium', 'medium'),
                                ('difficult', 'difficult'))
    difficulty_level = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=difficulty_level_options, default='medium')
    ingredients = models.TextField(max_length=1000000, null=True, blank=True)
    img_url = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/recipes', null=True, blank=True, default='static/recipes/no image.jpeg')

class Profile(models.Model):
    person_of = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_weight = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    goal_weight = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    calorie_count = models.FloatField(default=0, blank=True)
    food_selected = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    exercises_selected = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    time_hour_exercise = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    calorie_exercise = models.FloatField(null=False, default=0)
    quantity = models.FloatField(default=0)
    total_calorie = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True)
    total_calorie_exercise = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    calorie_goal = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1500, blank=True)
    all_food_selected_today = models.ManyToManyField(Food, through='PostFood', related_name='inventory')
    meat_type_choices = (
        ('breakfast', 'breakfast'),
        ('brunch', 'brunch'),
        ('lunch', 'lunch'),
        ('dinner', 'dinner'),
        ('supper', 'supper'),
        ('snacks', 'snacks'),
    )
    meat_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=meat_type_choices, default='breakfast')
    goal_water = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=3)
    current_water = models.FloatField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=0)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  # new
        if self.food_selected != None:
            self.amount = (self.food_selected.calorie / self.food_selected.quantity)
            self.calorie_count = self.amount * self.quantity
            self.total_calorie = self.calorie_count + self.total_calorie
            calories = Profile.objects.filter(person_of=self.person_of).last()
            PostFood.objects.create(profile=calories, food=self.food_selected, calorie_amount=self.calorie_count,
                                    amount=self.quantity, meat_type=self.meat_type)
            self.food_selected = None
            super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
     
        else:
            super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.person_of.username)


def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        person_of_profile = Profile(person_of=instance)
        person_of_profile.save()


post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)


class PostFood(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    calorie_amount = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    meat_type = models. CharField(max_length=50)
```

I select food from Food model and add to Profile food_selected.